# In Eclipse retrived info shows black screen

Tags: android

So I am a begginer at programming and have had a difficult time trying to create an application, but have had alot of help from this site so here it goes again. I am trying to show the retrived information from a login screen and I get no errors and nothing in logcat here is my code so far

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Loginretrieve extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String url = "http://beatswith.us/login.php";

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    try {

        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        Object responseString = getResponseString(response);



    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public static String getResponseString(HttpResponse response)
        throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

    String responseString = "";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                .getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
            Log.d("beats.us.with", "Output");
        }
        in.close();
        responseString = sb.toString();

    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return responseString;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting anything to be visible. use `setContentView(R.layout.main);` in the `onCreate()` method. The main.xml file should be automatically generated when create the project, it will only contain a textview but you should at least be able to see something. See here for info about [layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

Also you should look into [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for your login stuff, any network operations should be done in a different thread not on the UI thread.

Sample xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

to get the view

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(someValue);
```

where someValue is data you got from your server

Comment: Yes do use multithreading there is good chance this app will crash without it.

Comment: ok I created a xml file to show content view, Only thing is I want to show the content retrived from the website. Do I leave the xml file blank or will I have to code something in the xml file? Please help!

Comment: You would declare the views you want to populate in an xml file then get them using findViewById(R.id.name) then set the values. I'll edit my answer with a small example.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the information you must have a layout defined in xml or code to show your information in.

If you do have this already you must call

```
 setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);
```

in your oncreate

Comment: ok I created a xml file to show content view, Only thing is I want to show the content retrived from the website. Do I leave the xml file blank or will I have to code something in the xml file? Please help!